# jQuery submit method throws 'too much recursion'

Tags: jquery, submit

I'm facing the problem, that I want to validate my form against empty inputs.
This works as following:

```
mandatoryValues = new Array();

(...)
mandatoryValues.push('#field_1');
mandatoryValues.push('#field_2');
mandatoryValues.push('#field_3');
(...)


jQuery('#eventAddForm').submit(function() {

    var error;

    for(var i=0; i<mandatoryValues.length; i++) {

        if (jQuery(mandatoryValues[i] + '_field').val() == "") {
            jQuery(mandatoryValues[i] + '_label').addClass('error');
            error = true;
        } else {
            jQuery(mandatoryValues[i] + '_label').removeClass('error');
        }

    }

    if (error !== true) {
        jQuery('#eventAddForm').submit();
        return true;
    }

    return false;

});
```

When no error appears (`error` is NOT `true`), the form should be submitted.
The only thing that happens is, that I got "too much recursion" in console.

How to avoid that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake - sorry. 
I had a `onsubmit="return:false;"` in the `form`-tag, why ever.
So I don't need that and I don't need the second `.submit()`.

Thanks anyway for no comments ;p